# VBA to stop printing worksheet in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am preparing journal voucher in excel 2010. I want to minimize the error. Hence i need a VBA code which helps to stop printing voucher if to cells are not equal. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using `Workbook_BeforePrint`?

Comment: @Rooh, I have added a solution for you below. I noticed you are new here, so Welcome! and please remember to accept (click the arrow on the upper left of the answer) the answer that best solves your issue, and upvote any other helpful answers you recieve.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create an event. In the VBA editor, double click ThisWorkbook tab in the Project Explorer and enter this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") <> _
       Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") Then
    MsgBox "Cannot print. Values do not match"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can edit the cells (A1 on both sheet1 and sheet2 in my example) to be whatever you need. Make sure you save the workbook and open it with macros enabled for it to be active.